Changing the magnetic field of earth
I am familiar with the concept of toroid which causes an electromagnetic field.
Is it possible, if we make a large enough toroid, to change the magnetic field of earth.
If yes, then how will it affect the rotation of earth?
Also, if we build a toroid large enough with the strength of Earth's magnetic field, if placed in such a manner to cancel out the Earth's magnetic field, what will be the consequences?

A toroidal magnetic field loops around in circles inside the “donut”. The Earth’s field is nothing like that.

But would it should affect the rotational motion of the earth. And maybe the gravitational force will change too.

The change in both would be immeasurably small for the magnetic energies that human technology can produce.

In 2022, the total energy consumption of humanity was estimated at 24,398 terawatt-hours (about 24.398 terawatts continuously for the whole year), while the Earth's magnetic field's total energy is estimated at around $3\cdot10^{16}$ joules. This means that it would take around 49 minutes for every generating device on the entire planet to generate a comparable amount of energy as the Earth's magnetic field.
How we would use that power is an unanswered question here. We can't just build a little handheld torus, channel terawatts of energy through it, and call it a day - the torus would melt and then vaporize immediately. Lasers in the tens of kilowatts range are used for missile defense and can destroy objects at medium range; a terawatt is a billion kilowatts (thus a trillion watts); a kiloton of TNT is only about 4.2 terajoules (4.2 terawatt-seconds), so channeling that much power into basically anything in any way would be equivalent to detonating tactical nuclear weapons on it multiple times a second - for almost an hour. It is not feasible with foreseeable technologies to efficiently produce, let alone effectively use, that much power.
Lastly, if we did do it somehow, our super-electromagnet would be exactly that - an electromagnet. It's implausible to consider actually measurably changing the movement of the Earth's core - it weighs on the order of $10^{24}$ kilograms, and we're dealing with power outputs more than ten orders of magnitude smaller. Sure, you could affect the Earth's rotation by slowly moving the core around with an ultra-strong EM field, but you'd be better off going into space and hurling asteroids at the Earth at shallow angles to change its spin. If you just magically cancelled out Earth's magnetic field, it would be as if it were not there, as expected; we would all bake in radiation and die. And no, the gravitational field would definitely not be affected.

On top of that, usually terawatt lasers are for tiny timescales. They are more like watts if you include the time left off, and they take some kilowatts to run. Just storage and waste of the energies involved would be a tremendously serious issue.

How will it not affect the gravitational field? Also why wouldn't it affect earth's magnetic field because eventually something must happen

@SurajsingRajput In physics, you never ask why something shouldn't happen, you always ask why it should - it is much more difficult to deny every possible route to something happening vs. identifying one possible route to it happening. Gravity does not care, in a superficial sense, about the electromagnetic field (at least for energy densities as low as we're talking about).

@controlgroup thanks for the correction. So you are saying that gravity will act the way it has and it should and electromagnetic field will act the way it usually does so no consequences? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Generally no the EM field does not affect gravity except in very extreme circumstances (i.e. charged black holes). And the EM field generated by any reasonable electromagnet can't appreciably affect the Earth's magnetic field

Okay. Thanks!
